# can we build a Mac installer with a delayed restart?

Tags: macos, installation

We have built a Mac OSX installer which includes a driver that support some functinalities, hence we need to restart the machine after the installation. However, i wouldn't want to force it, but to allow users to postpone the restart for later (and meanwhile using the software without the driver)

we couldn't find any option for that - something like a message box that would say 'restart' with Now/Later buttons.

any ideas, anyone?

thanks much
Lior

Comment: Why do you need to add that to the installer? The user can simply leave the installer open until he/she is ready to restart.

Comment: you are right, indeed they can leave the installer open and return to it later, but less experienced users would not do it. They would 'follow instructions' and restart immediately. moreover, most of the functionality is available without restarting

Answer (score 2):

If the user wants to restart "later" then they will restart. If you feel you need to remind them that they need to, then put that reminder in your application, not the installer.

Comment: hi NSD, thanks for your answer - and see above for the need for the message box

Answer (score 0):

Windows Installer does what you're talking about, a constant pop-up every few hours with "Would you like to restart now? [even though you said no the last 20 times I bugged you]".  It's horrible.  Don't do it.  If the user says later, then they mean later.  Don't bug them.

If they try to use a feature in your app that requires the restart, then you can tell them that feature is unavailable until after a restart.  Otherwise, no bugging please.